# Displaying attributes for features within current map extent in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, extents, mosaic

I have found Landsat 8 PanSharpened WMS service [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c34fd380d16f40a7bb7995ac4d7ab8de). It is a mosaic made by Esri.

I can open attribute table of this mosaic dataset.

**Can I sort rows of attribute table to see only rows related to rasters in my current view extent using ArcGIS for Desktop?**

The option I need is similar to [Attribute Table widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-attribute-table.htm)'s `Filter by Map Extent`:

> Only displays attributes for features within the current map extent

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a [spatial definition query](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54401/115).

Comment: No, it is not spatial definition query. See update.

Comment: It sounds to me like the Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS has implemented a simple spatial definition query, but can you [edit] your question to make clear whether you are using that or ArcGIS for Desktop, please?

Comment: Yes, I use ArcGIS for Desktop. Question edited.

Comment: At the moment I able to use `Select Features` tool for described in questions purposes but its not an automate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds to me like a Spatial Definition Query which is currently at the [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000884QAAQ) stage for ArcMap.

I suggest that you add your vote to it, if you have not already.

You may want to submit a new ArcGIS Idea in case the existing one, which is more elaborate, does not cover the simpler `Filter by Map Extent` that you envisage.

Comment: This functionality is way overdue - QGIS has had it for a long time. 

I searched the ArcGIS Ideas site and found this:  https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/12089

Answer (score 2):

Some idea...You can work around the problem by creating a Python add-in.

Do job when Tool is clicked (or onKeyDown(self, keycode, shift) ).
Next  tool are triggered and do:

```
#get extend
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
XMIN = df.extent.XMin
YMIN = df.extent.YMin
XMAX = df.extent.XMax
YMAX = df.extent.YMax

#create polygon from extend
#....

#use arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management
#get list of selected object
#
#add layer.definitionQuery to layer
#refres view and table
```

It's just an idea...

Comment: Yes, this will work.